# Visualizing stop over duration of marked individuals in R using ggplot

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, duration

I want to visualize the stopover duration and timing of several individually marked animals in a single plot. All individuals should be drawn on the y - axis, time on x - axis. I want every observation to be represented by a dot. To indicate the presence of an individual despite it was not observed on every day the minimum stopover interval (time from first to last observation) should be indicated by a solid or dashed line. Simplified my raw data look like this:

```
    date            individual
1   10.02.15         Y1
2   10.02.15         Y3
3   11.02.15         Y1
4   15.02.15         Y1
```

I transformed the date into day of year and tried to plot using ggplot but don´t manage to draw the dots or lines.

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_dotplot.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.csv("YourData.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$date <- dmy(df$date)

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = individual), size = 10) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = individual, group = individual))
```